# How to change toolbar direction in API 16?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have problem with changing ActionBar(Toolbar) direction from LTR to RTL in Navigation Drawer Activity. 
Also tested different codes but even when whole of program direction changed, the toolbar did not change.
Can you help me?

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: `code` if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            getWindows().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }